# Get list of Chrome Windows (OS-Level)

Tags: webdriver-io

[image]

I thought initially that I could retrieve Chrome Windows by using:

```
browser.getWindowHandles()
```

Problem with that is that it doesn't actually get Chrome "Window" but Tabs. Is there anyway in Selenium to have a concept of real "visual" Chrome window? I want to know if a Tab is from a specific Window and how many tabs in a Window specifically. The doc is misleading especially with getAllWindowHandles which implies that it's about Window.

I'm basically looking for a solution to get "OS Window" and their tabs. I've switched from Selenium to WebdriverIO maybe thinking it's possible but I can't find in the docs.

Thanks guys for the help!

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34655248/6793637

Windows and Tabs are similar , it depends on the browser setting whether the new link should be open in a tab or window.

if you open a new window or tab both will be detected in selenium/wdio . Note that the tab or window count is for the window that was opened by the selenium session and not the entire windows opened in your system

eg

```
it('should login with valid credentials', async () => {
    await LoginPage.open();
    // opens new tab
    await browser.execute((a) => { window.open(a) }, 'http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login')
    await expect((await browser.getWindowHandles()).length).toBe(2);
    //opens new window
    await browser.execute((a) => { window.open(a, 'target', 'features') }, 'http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login')
    await expect((await browser.getWindowHandles()).length).toBe(3);
    await browser.pause(5000);
});
```